# How to override or extend Product List Page template to show Icon on Product Images in Magento Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template, custom-block, grid-layout

Consider the Below Image
[image]

I want to show an Icon on the Image of each product. I am developing an extension and I want to do this task via that extension, independent of theme. How can I achieve this task. what Blocks I've to extend. Any kind of suggestion and help will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Updated:

After adding the suggested code I'm getting the below error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a layout XML file inside of your module. In this layout XML file you can reference product list block and change it's template.

```
<layout>
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourmodule/product/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourmodule/product/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Please check update in question I'm getting errors after including the code

Comment: Can you share your module's layout xml?

Comment: Also enable error reporting on site so that you can debug the issue.

You can follow below link to enable error reporting:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143406/how-to-turn-on-magento-error-messages

Comment: Also replace template file path with correct once.